# Linq - Select Date from DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, datetime

I have a `Linq` Result from which I need to select only `Date` from `DateTime`.
My Query goes like this :

```
var UserTemplates = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
                     where xx.USER_ID == userid && xx.IS_ACTIVE == 1
                     select new
                     {
                       xx.TEMPLATE_ID,
                       xx.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                       //CREATED_DATE = xx.CREATED_DATE.Value.Date
                       //CREATED_DATE = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(xx.CREATED_DATE)
                       xx.CREATED_DATE
                     }).ToList();
```

Is that Possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATED_DATE - `datetime` datatype
```

Actually,I'm Binding it to a Control as a `DataSource` and the control is displaying both `Date and Time`.But I want to display only `date`.

When I'm trying with `CREATED_DATE = xx.CREATED_DATE.Value.Date`,It is giving an error like :

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: xx.CREATED_DATE.ToShortDateString() ? What format is CREATED_DATE?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it is for presentation purpose, then you can use `DataFormatString` property. For Example, if you are binding a datasource to a GridView, you could do as;

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CREATED_DATE" ...
     DataFormatString="{0:d}" ../>
```

Else you can use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) which returns the input date without the time portion.

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(xx.CREATED_DATE)
```

Your query would be like;

```
var UserTemplates = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
                     where xx.USER_ID == userid && xx.IS_ACTIVE == 1
                     select new
                     {
                       xx.TEMPLATE_ID,
                       xx.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                       EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(xx.CREATED_DATE) //new like
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: In the newer versions of Entity Framework, `EntityFunctions` has been replaced by `DbFunctions`.

Comment: and in Entity Framework Core neither EntityFunctions nor DbFunctions is needed, date fields handle .Date nicely

Answer (score 2):

Use this...It worked for me..

```
var UserTemplates = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
                     where xx.USER_ID == userid && xx.IS_ACTIVE == 1
                     select new
                     {
                       xx.TEMPLATE_ID,
                       xx.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                       CREATED_DATE=SqlFunctions.DateName("day", xx.CREATED_DATE).Trim() + "/" +
        SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)xx.CREATED_DATE.Value.Month).TrimStart() + "/" +
        SqlFunctions.DateName("year", xx.CREATED_DATE)
         }).ToList();
```

And Output Date will be dd/MM/yyyy format

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this ?

```
var qry = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
           where xx.USER_ID == userid && xx.IS_ACTIVE == 1
           select new { xx.TEMPLATE_ID, xx.TEMPLATE_NAME, xx.xx.CREATED_DATE });

var UserTemplates = qry.AsEnumerable().Select(xx => new 
                    {
                       xx.TEMPLATE_ID,
                       xx.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                       xx.CREATED_DATE.Value.Date 
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't have any property like '.Date'. It only has property like '.Value.Date' and that's not working and giving an error like :
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @RealSteel This, should work if you follow it completely. The reason being is that the `.Date` call is running in Linq to Object rather than Linq to Entities. Still. It isn't my preferred solution.

Comment: @Aron It is also not my preferred solution. If the value is obtained for display purposes i wouldn't even care to make it a date from within the query at all. The control should have a FormatString for the display value.

Comment: Getting this error: {"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserTemplates = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
                     where xx.USER_ID == userid && xx.IS_ACTIVE == 1 select  xx).AsEnumerable()
                     .Select( i=> new
                     {
                       i.TEMPLATE_ID,
                       i.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                       CREATED_DATE = i.CREATED_DATE.ToString("M/d/yyyy"),
                       i.CREATED_DATE
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var UserTemplates = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
                 where xx.USER_ID == userid && xx.IS_ACTIVE == 1
                 select new Attributes
                 {
                   TEMPLATE_ID=xx.TEMPLATE_ID,
                   TEMPLATE_NAME=xx.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                   dateCreatd = xx.CREATED_DATE                      
                 })
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .select(p=>new Attributes
                 {
                   TEMPLATE_ID =p.TEMPLATE_ID,
                   TEMPLATE_NAME=p.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                   dateString = p.dateCreatd .Value.toString("YYYY-MMM-dd")                       
                 }).ToList();


public class Attributes
{
 public string TEMPLATE_ID { get; set; }
 public string TEMPLATE_NAME { get; set }
 public DateTime dateCreatd { get; set; }
 public string dateString { get; set; }

}
```

hopes it is useful to you