# 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In My sql db  is Date , when i am using entity linq where clause , i am facing issue like "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." this is my where clause

```
TeamWorks.work_plan_dt == DateTime.Now.Date
var t = uow.TeamWork.GetAll().Where(t => t.work_plan_dt.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
public DateTime? work_plan_dt { get; set; }
```

I have used `dbfunctions.truncatetime` and `EntityFunctions.truncatetime` still I am facing the issue , i should not change the datatype in db side from date to datetime , please help me

Advance thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear but it seems like the issue actually has nothing to do with what you think (the date type), please post the actual code that is giving you this error.

Comment: Why not just `DateTime.Today` ?

Comment: TeamWorks.work_plan_dt.Date == DateTime.Today.Date,

Comment: public datetime? work_plan_dt {get; set;}

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. -->getting error like this

Comment: code: var t = uow.TeamWork.GetAll().Where(t => t.work_plan_dt.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);

Comment: use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49319997/4627336 it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call your c# methods inside your linq code since there is no translation for them. If you have a datetime value, just calculate the value that you need and then pass it to linq query.

Like this

```
var someDate = DateTime.Now.AddDay(1);
var list = Db.MyTable.Where(x=>x.Date>someDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
var t = uow.TeamWork.GetAll().Where(t => t.work_plan_dt.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
```

To this:

```
var t = ((from x in uow.TeamWork.GetAll() select x).ToList().Where(
                             T => T.work_plan_dt.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).ToList()
```

Or this:

```
var t = uow.TeamWork.GetAll().ToList().Where(t => t.work_plan_dt.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
```