# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime GetDate()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I just started leaning asp.net a couple of months ago and I have some few issues. I receive this error `LINQ` to Entities does not recognize the method `System.DateTime GetDate()` method, on the browser while this code works perfectly in Linq. According to what I read in several forum, this error occurs when `Linq` to Entities cannot translate the code into an SQL query. But I still can't figure out what is wrong with my method.
Here is the class that has the `GetDate()` method

```cs
public class Cycle
{
    private DateTime _Date;

    public DateTime Date 
    { 
        get => _Date;

        set => _Date = value;
    }

    public DateTime GetDate ()
    {
        return this._Date;
    }
}
```

Here is query that call the method

```cs
var RouteList = from site in Sites
                orderby site.Community.Name ascending
                where site.Season.SeasonYear == 2019 && site.Yard.YardID == 1 && site.SiteType.SiteTypeDescription.Equals("A")
                select new Status
                {
                    Pin = site.Pin,
                    Community = site.Community.Name,

                    Cycle1 = ((from sbm in SBMs where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID select new Cycle { Date = sbm.CrewSite.Crew.TodayDate }).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()).Equals(null)
                         ? (DateTime?)null : ((from sbm in SBMs where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID select new Cycle { Date = sbm.CrewSite.Crew.TodayDate }).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()).GetDate()
```

Can someone help me find out how I can adjust my method ?

Comment: GetDate() can't be translated to an SQL statement. If you just want the date part of the field, you would use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime)

Comment: I tried it but I still get the same error

Comment: How about if you try `Cycle1 = ((from sbm in SBMs where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew) }).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()).Equals(null)
                             ? (DateTime?)null : ((from sbm in SBMs where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew)}).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()).Date`

Comment: You are a genius. It works. 
Thanks Selim

Comment: You are welcome, I've added as a answer. Please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539559/5519709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) for getting Date of DateTime and use `Date` property of `Cycle` instead of custom `GetDate` method:

```
var RouteList = from site in Sites
                    orderby site.Community.Name ascending
                    where site.Season.SeasonYear == 2019 && site.Yard.YardID == 1 && site.SiteType.SiteTypeDescription.Equals("A")
                    select new Status
                    {
                        Pin = site.Pin,
                        Community = site.Community.Name,

                         Cycle1 = ((from sbm in SBMs where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew) }).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()).Equals(null)
                             ? (DateTime?)null : ((from sbm in SBMs where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew)}).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()).Date

...
```

Comment: Hi Selim, I can't still take out the time part. I tried the DbFuntions.TruncateTime() method to no avail

Comment: Did you add `System.Data.Entity` namespace?

Comment: Yes I did. but the truncating function doesn't remove the time part

Comment: I also tried to put it in the Cycle Class but nothing changed

Comment: Hmm I think this would be another question since it is hard to understand. Also it depends EF version etc.. too. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021606/linq-select-date-from-datetime or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588033/get-date-part-only-from-datetime-value-using-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks for your help. i really appreciate it. I'll put it as another question